# Does Quickblox Conferencing Works as a Call?

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I am Developing an App which needs to Call (Audio/Video) to Users, Add them in ongoing Call like whatsapp does and one more functionality that the users can join a call.
I got to know that for joining Quickblox Conferencing should be used.
But I am unable to get any callback for any conference started.

**Does Conference feature act as a call also??**

Answer (score 0):

[QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/) offers 2 ways of implmenting multi-party calls:

1. Peer-2-peer calls, allowing up to 4 participants at once. This feature is available with all plans including the free one.
2. Conference calls using SFU technology, allowing up to 12 participants at once. This is feature is available on the Enterprise plan but it is possible to request a demo.

Apart from native OS support, QuickBlox also has [React Native SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/react-native-video-calling) and [Flutter SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-video-calling).